# Textbox is not getting printed from a Dialog box in Javascript/Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, printing

I am trying to print a dialog box. I am able to print everything from the dialog box except the `Textbox` values.

#### HTML

```
<div class="calculator">
 <a href="#" onclick="printElement('.calculator')">
   <img src="images/icon_print.png" /> Print
 </a>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
function printElement(element) {
    var text = document.getElementById("age_input").value;
    alert(text);
    w = window.open();
    w.document.write($(element).html());
    w.document.close();
    document.getElementById("age_input").value = text;
    w.print();

    w.close();
}
```

How do I print the dialog with the values in the `Textbox` elements included?

Comment: document.write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. It took me a while to figure it out. The issue is that the content of the text box is not part of HTML when you use `$(element).html()`

You can see this by inspecting the element by any browser dev tools (F12). Therefore you must make your content part of HTML to make them available during print. A quick workaround is to use `placeholder` attribute of the input box. Here's an updated version of your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function printElement(element) {
         var text = document.getElementById("age_input").value;
         document.getElementById("age_input").placeholder = text;
         w = window.open();
         w.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
         w.document.write('</head><body >');
         w.document.write($(element).html());
         w.document.write('</body></html>');
         w.document.close();
         document.getElementById("age_input").value = text;
         w.print();

         w.close();
     } 
 </script>
```

I assume `age_input` is your input box and it's within the Div element

```
<div class="calculator">
        <input id="age_input" type="text" />
 <a href="#" onclick="printElement('.calculator')"> <img src="images/icon_print.png" />Print</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sam, your solution did work! Cheers :)